# process-exporter return "1" , ideally should be "2" or "0"

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-process-exporter

I am monitoring process with process-exporter, the config in conf.yaml is like

```
    process_names:
  - name: "{{.Matches}}"
    cmdline:
    - 'datanode'
```

"datanode" is the keyword to identify the process. Ideally the value should return "2" when process is up and "0" while process is down. But sometimes the return value can be "1" for some CDH cluster process like datanode while the process is actually running,but at the sametime has error in log. Any one can advise what value "1" means? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one match in the process string. Therefore 0 means no matches (no process running), anything else simply means some process with that string is running, and so adjust your PromQL accordingly. Ideally, you only get 1 or 0, so you'd need to be more explicit about the `cmdline` entry.

For Java processes, you could also use JMX exporter rather than process exporter and write query based on lack of data to discover down services. Or Blackbox exporter to hit Hadoop Namenode and Datanode TCP/HTTP ports.